# Turn an image into a json polygon

Tags: json, d3.js, geojson, dc.js

I have an image that looks like the following but without out the colors. I need to create a JSON file that represent the polygons that would draw this. How would i go about acomplishing this. In needs to be in a format that can be used my dc.js preferabaly the same way that a map is saved